# BalloonTip can I set diffrent colors to the title?

Tags: c#

`notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip`
1. Can I set the title to a diffrent color?
2. Can I prevent one ballon tip to override the previous one? that means to wait until the previous dissapear and only then show?

```
notifyIcon.ShowBalloon(20000, "My Title", "My Text", ToolTipIcon.Info);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Michael can you show us how you are displaying the BalloonTip in your application? The code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first question, you could create a derived tooltip class, documentation [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/19994c9f-bdaa-4c4c-bcb4-5c60cb241134).

For your second question, if the tooltips come from the same app and point to the same icon, the new tooltip should make the previous one disappear, so only one tooltip will show at a time. I found this documentation about it

> Issue #3: One Balloon at a Time
>
> Only one balloon tip can appear on the
>   system tray at one time.  If an
>   application attempts to display a
>   second balloon tip, the first balloon
>   is closed immediately (regardless of
>   the timeout setting) and the second
>   balloon appears.  However, if the
>   first balloon was displayed by another
>   application, it won't close until its
>   timeout expires, at which point the
>   second balloon will appear.